# Process of finding intersecting points between two functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, quadratics

I have to find the intersecting points of these two functions
$$f(x)=e^x-5x+7$$
and
$$g(x)=2x^2+16x+2$$

I know how to do this with two quadratic equations, by putting the two functions equal to each other, but *f(x)* is confusing me, because i don't know what to do with the *e<sup>x</sup>*

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get a "nice" number by solving this analytically. You may need to use root-finding methods such as Newton's method (or just use the "intersect" feature on your graphing calculator).

Comment: You definately won't obtain a "nice" number as a solution ;)